# How do I use BigDecimal's setScale to get two digits precision

Tags: java

```
public class Dummy {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String x = "1.234.567,89 EUR";
        String e = " EUR";

        List<BigDecimal> totals = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
        totals.add( new BigDecimal(x.replaceAll(" EUR","").replaceAll("\\.","").replaceAll(",",".")));
        System.out.println(totals.get(0).add(new BigDecimal(0.10).setScale(3,0)));
    }
}
```

With current code I get `1234567.991` and setting it to `setScale(2,0)` I get `1234568.00` what I am looking for is `1234567.99`. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
System.out.println(totals.get(0).add(new BigDecimal(0.10)
                                     .setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)));
```

Out put

```
1234567.99
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be an inbuilt Java function for this. But otherwise, you can do it with simple mathematics.

You can multiply the number with 100. And then use ceiling or floor function of Java. And then divide it with 100. You got your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use

```
new BigDecimal(0.10)
```

which is both inprecise and does not give a precision/scale of 2.
But use

```
new BigDecimal("0.10")
```

This preserves the scale.

Answer (score 0):

This will give desired output.

If you want to go with double at that time we can use DecimalFormat but in bigdecimal setScale is used.

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(1234567.991).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
.doubleValue();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1234567.99
```